# Can serial-term interpret new line characters as CR LF?

Tags: character-encoding

I'd like to read a serial link from Emacs using `serial-term`. The output looks wrong, like if the new line characters did not trigger carriage return:

```
First line
          Second line
                     Third line
```

Reading from this serial line using `ansi-term` shows the expected output:

```
A first line
A second line
Third line
```

I tried to use `set-buffer-file-coding-system` to `unix` in the `serial-term` buffer, but this did not change anything.

Is it possible to get `serial-term` to interpret new line characters as carriage return and a line feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution, that doesn't involve modifying the Emacs source. I copy the definition of `serial-term` from `term.el` and provide a process filter that inserts `\r` before any `\n` before passing the output to the `term-mode` process filter.

```el
(defun replace-all (string to-find to-replace)
  (let ((index  (cl-search to-find string))
        (pos    0)
        (result ""))
    (while index
      (setq result (concat result
                           (substring string pos index)
                           to-replace)
            pos    (+ index (length to-find))
            index  (cl-search to-find string :start2 pos)))
    (concat result (substring string pos))))

(defun rephone-serial-process-filter (process output)
  "Replace LF in output string with CR+LF."
  (term-emulate-terminal process
                         (replace-all output
                                      (byte-to-string ?\n)
                                      (string ?\r ?\n))))

(defun rephone-serial-term (port)
  "Basically duplicate SERIAL-TERM from term.el but with process
  filtering to translate LF to CR+LF."
  (interactive (list (serial-read-name)))
  (serial-supported-or-barf)
  (let* ((process (make-serial-process
                   :port port
                   :speed 115200
                   :bytesize 8
                   :parity nil
                   :stopbits 1
                   :flowcontrol nil
                   :coding 'raw-text-unix
                   :noquery t
                   :name (format "Lua:%s" port)
                   :filter 'rephone-serial-process-filter
                   :sentinel 'term-sentinel))
         (buffer (process-buffer process)))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (term-mode)
      (term-line-mode)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (set-marker (process-mark process) (point)))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)
    buffer))
```

Answer (score 0):

Patch to ${emacs_root}/lisp/term.el:

```
--- term.el 2016-10-06 01:34:52.000000000 +0800
+++ fix-term.el 2016-10-06 01:35:25.000000000 +0800
@@ -2857,6 +2857,8 @@ See `term-prompt-regexp'."
          (term-vertical-motion 0)
          (setq term-current-column term-start-line-column))
             ((eq char ?\n)  ;; (terminfo: cud1, ind)
+             (term-vertical-motion 0)
+             (setq term-current-column term-start-line-column)
          (unless (and term-kill-echo-list
                   (term-check-kill-echo-list))
            (term-down 1 t)))
```